# Flavor mixing Higgs Yukawa term with both left and right chiral neutrinos and with generic masses

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, resource-recommendations, neutrinos, beyond-the-standard-model

In p.727 of Peskin QFT, it derives a flavor mixing Higgs Yukawa term, but he **assumes that the neutrinos have no mass.**

However we know that we can include both left and right chiral neutrinos, and also introduce Dirac or Majorana masses to them.

In this sense, p.727 of Peskin QFT is not suitable discussion for nowadays since **we do know neutrinos have mass.**

### Question

> Are there pedagogical refs/literatures on (1) the flavor mixing Higgs Yukawa term and (2) weak $W$ current basis change discussion when we include both left and right chiral neutrinos, and also introduce Dirac or Majorana masses to them?

[image]

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: Please fix your previous three questions today as well. They all have images of text and math.

Comment: You guys should focus on physics instead of focus on being an admin police...?

Comment: (also the image of book text is supportive, it is not 100% necessary to provide. it just that it will be easier for people to see where I am referring to)

Comment: [This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/414173/gim-mechanism-in-cheng-and-lis-mu-to-e-gamma-calculation) and the ones linked to it review the 1-loop calculation μ ⟶ eγ of the outstanding textbook by Cheng & Li, *Gauge theory of elementary particle interactions*, section 13.3, pp 420-427, going through an internal massive neutrino line. It is the close analog of b⟶s γ at one loop.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos -- thank you so much! this is what I wanted to hear. The solid real physics (not the Admin type of boring non physics.)

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/276880/calculating-the-mu-rightarrow-e-gamma-decay-and-cancellation-between-diagrams) and [also](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/414173/gim-mechanism-in-cheng-and-lis-mu-to-e-gamma-calculation).

Comment: thanks Cosmas Zachos -- but I am asking likely something slightly different "the flavor mixing Higgs Yukawa term with both left and right chiral neutrinos and with generic masses" (and how many CP violating phases one can get. The Peskin QFT does not provide such general discussions, but only left neutrinos without masses)

Comment: The P&S discussion does not posit R neutrinos, but the question appears to ask about them, and all modern estimates cover several scenarios of neutrino masses.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos, can you give one excellent short ref on that with all neutrino masses and how to check whether there is CP violation phase in the weak lepton sector? (Is that PMNS?)

Comment: Hmmm don’t know of one, but will look...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117722/discussion-between-annie-marie-heart-and-cosmas-zachos).